# CSS isn't showing up on a specific part of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on a website I'm building and am in the process of consolidating stylesheets. I'm currently having a problem where one div section of the page is not connecting to the stylesheet. The rest of the page is fine but it's just this one section and I have no idea why. I copied and pasted it (html and style) from the first draft and am using the same fonts and bootstrap cdn (bootstrap fonts 4.1 and bootstrap cdn 3.3.7) but am getting different results. Would appreciate any help you could offer.

here's the html

```
<div class="main">
                    <div class="container">
                    <header>
                        <center><h2>My Work</h2></center>
                    </header>
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="image featured"><img src="laptopstock.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                        <h3><a href="sampleofficial.html">Arris SURFboard SBG6700-AC Wireless Gateway Manual</a></h3>      
                            <p>The Arris SURFboard SBG6700-AC wireless gateway is the premier modem on the market today. It's top of the line security, simple user interface and blazing fast speeds make it the number one consumer choice for modems. With this guide you can set up your home wireless network in 30 minutes.</p>
                            <br>
                            <p><a href="sampleofficial.html" class="button-alt">Learn More</a></p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

here's the css

```
        main {
            padding: 8em 0;
        }

            main.header {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0em 0 3em 0;
                padding-top: 1000em;
            }
    /* difference between padding and margin? 
    padding is on the inside. 
    margin on the outside.*/
    /* this is the gray space between the header and the image */

                main.header h2 {
                    font-size: 2.75em;
                    margin: 0;
                    letter-spacing: .005em;
                    color: #000;
                }

        body.landing main {
            margin-top: -14em;
        }
    .container {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      width: 100%;
    }
.box {
                margin: 1em;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                padding: 2em 2em !important;
            }

                .box.features .features-row {
                    border-top: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                    .box.features .features-row section {
                        border: 0;
                        border-top: solid 1px #e5e5e5 !important;
                        float: none;
                        margin: 2em 0 0 0 !important;
                        padding: 2em 0 0 0 !important;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    .box.features .features-row:first-child section:first-child {
                        border-top: 0 !important;
                        margin-top: 0 !important;
                        padding-top: 0 !important;
                    }

                .box .image.featured {
                    margin-left: -2em;
                    width: calc(100% + 4em);
                }

                    .box .image.featured:first-child {
                        margin-bottom: 2em;
                        margin-top: -2em;
                    }

                    .box .image.featured:last-child {
                        margin-bottom: -2em;
                        margin-top: 2em;
                    }
```

Comment: `main` is not a CSS selector. Try `.main`, it is a class. Also, you ar jumbling up class/element selectors. It should be `.main header`, not `main.header`

Comment: You made many mistakes with your css selectors. First try .main instead of main and it should be .main header instead of main.header

Answer (score 1):

Your element selector is wrong. From your html, 'main' is a class, 'header' is an element. To refer to class in css, use '.' as in .main, to refer to element, use the tag name directly. Writing main.header means and element 'main' that has class 'header' which is not what you want. Use the Css instead;

```
.main {
        padding: 8em 0;
    }

        .main header {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0em 0 3em 0;
            padding-top: 1000em;
        }
/* difference between padding and margin? 
padding is on the inside. 
margin on the outside.*/
/* this is the gray space between the header and the image */

            .main header h2 {
                font-size: 2.75em;
                margin: 0;
                letter-spacing: .005em;
                color: #000;
            }
```

That should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried that it did not work. I also tried switching it to div id="main" and #main in the css but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

center tag is deprecated in your html header.  Replace with text-align in css.  An example would be:  h2 { text-align: center; }